# Connect Behringer crave USB MIDI to Ardour

Tags: midi, ardour

I am trying to sync a Behringer crave over USB midi and control it from Ardour.

I can see it in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1397:121e BEHRINGER International GmbH CRAVE
```

But not in `amidi -l` or `arecordmidi -l`.
output from `lsusb -v -d 1397:121e`:

```
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1397 BEHRINGER International GmbH
  idProduct          0x121e 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0065
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength       0x0009
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr(0)        1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      3 MIDI Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      MIDIStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength       0x0041
      MIDIStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 6
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (MIDI_IN_JACK)
        bJackType               1 Embedded
        bJackID                 1
        iJack                   0 
      MIDIStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 6
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (MIDI_IN_JACK)
        bJackType               2 External
        bJackID                 2
        iJack                   0 
      MIDIStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (MIDI_OUT_JACK)
        bJackType               1 Embedded
        bJackID                 3
        bNrInputPins            1
        baSourceID( 0)          2
        BaSourcePin( 0)         1
        iJack                   0 
      MIDIStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (MIDI_OUT_JACK)
        bJackType               2 External
        bJackID                 4
        bNrInputPins            1
        baSourceID( 0)          1
        BaSourcePin( 0)         1
        iJack                   0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        MIDIStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 5
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (GENERAL)
          bNumEmbMIDIJack         1
          baAssocJackID( 0)       1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        MIDIStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 5
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (GENERAL)
          bNumEmbMIDIJack         1
          baAssocJackID( 0)       3

grep . /sys/module/snd_usb_audio/parameters/*
/sys/module/snd_usb_audio/parameters/autoclock:Y
/sys/module/snd_usb_audio/parameters/device_setup:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
/sys/module/snd_usb_audio/parameters/enable:Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
/sys/module/snd_usb_audio/parameters/id:(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
/sys/module/snd_usb_audio/parameters/ignore_ctl_error:N
/sys/module/snd_usb_audio/parameters/index:-2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
/sys/module/snd_usb_audio/parameters/pid:-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
/sys/module/snd_usb_audio/parameters/quirk_alias:(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
```

`cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf1a8000 irq 136
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xdf080000 irq 17`

`dmesg | tail
[ 7727.453644] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 7727.606809] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1397, idProduct=121e, bcdDevice= 2.00
[ 7727.606814] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7727.606818] usb 1-3: Product: CRAVE
[ 7727.606821] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Behringer
[ 7727.606823] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: V001
[ 7727.728596] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[ 7727.786086] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[ 7728.013801] usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 7728.325787] usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd`

What can I do?

Comment: This means that the snd-usb-audio driver has not picked it up. Does it require a separate driver in Windows? Please show the output of `lsusb -v -d 1397:121e`.

Comment: answer in edit above

Comment: This looks like a perfectly valid class-compliant device. As root, run `rmmod snd-usb-audio; modprobe snd-usb-audio`. Are there any error messages in the system log (`dmesg | tail`)?

Comment: no error messages

Comment: Does the device show up in `/proc/asound/cards`? What is the output of `grep . /sys/module/snd_usb_audio/parameters/*`?

Comment: not showing in /proc/asound/card. it only supports midi not sound

Comment: adding output of grep above

Comment: Both audio and MIDI devices should show up in `/proc/asound/cards`.

Comment: Please show the contents of `/proc/asound/cards`, and all the new messages at the end of the output of `dmesg` when you re-plug the device.

Comment: @CL. added above

Comment: Those "reset" lines show that the PC (or the device) did not like what happened on the USB bus. Please try a different cable, a different USB port (not USB3) if available, and/or a different PC.